# Comparison between caching techniques for volley

Tags: android, image, caching, memory-management, android-volley

Which Caching technique, between **LRUCache**, **BitmapLRUCache**, **DiskLRUCache** is best for Volley hitting api having huge number of images.

If it matter, i am showing images in recycler View.

Motto is to get good memory management.

Comment: [Don't ask about... Product or service recommendations or comparisons, requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @Selvin,aye aye sir, btw thanks for not trolling me

Answer (score 1):

Please check this links after referring this u will get clear answers ... google made official document for volley caching which is really awesome with detail

First refer this link
https://blog.jayway.com/2013/10/04/image-caching-with-volley/[enter link description here](https://blog.jayway.com/2013/10/04/image-caching-with-volley/)

Second go for google official

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

I love too work with bitmaps because it is always challenging for android developer to cache bitmap properly otherwise OutOfMemory exception is common.Those 2 links helped me a lot

If u have any questions u can ask